Does GSON 2.10.1 support Java 17?
We have a kotlin(version 1.9.21) service which ran on Java 11, we are planning to migrate to Java 17. But facing errors all related to Gson(version 2.10.1)
java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.gilecode.yagson.com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$DefaultBoundField cannot access a member of class with modifiers "private final"
    at com.gilecode.yagson.com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:430)
    at io.gsonfire.util.JsonUtils.toJsonTree(JsonUtils.java:60)
    at io.gsonfire.gson.HooksTypeAdapter.write(HooksTypeAdapter.java:46)
    at com.gilecode.yagson.com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:693)
    at com.gilecode.yagson.com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:674)
    at com.gilecode.yagson.com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:662)
    at com.gilecode.yagson.com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:637)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)    
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.gilecode.yagson.com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$DefaultBoundField cannot access a member of class com.inin.wfm.api.dto.forecasting.shortterm.bu.StoredShortTermForecastResultResponseApi with modifiers "private final"
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:392)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:674)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkAccess(Field.java:1102)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:423)
    at com.gilecode.yagson.com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$DefaultBoundField.getFieldValue(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
    at com.gilecode.yagson.com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$DefaultBoundField.writeField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:278)
    at com.gilecode.yagson.com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:425)

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for class. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
at com.gilecode.yagson.com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$17.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:267)
    at com.gilecode.yagson.com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.getInstance(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:411)
    at com.gilecode.yagson.com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.readOptionallyAdvisedInstance(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:380)
    at com.gilecode.yagson.adapters.TypeAdvisableComplexTypeAdapter.read(TypeAdvisableComplexTypeAdapter.java:51)
    at io.gsonfire.gson.HooksTypeAdapter.deserialize(HooksTypeAdapter.java:91)
    at io.gsonfire.gson.HooksTypeAdapter.read(HooksTypeAdapter.java:59)
    at com.gilecode.yagson.refs.impl.ReferencesNoneModeContext.doRead(ReferencesNoneModeContext.java:62)
    at com.gilecode.yagson.ReadContext.doRead(ReadContext.java:80)
    at com.gilecode.yagson.com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:915)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot allocate class.
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot allocate class Colgeneration
    at com.gilecode.yagson.com.google.gson.internal.UnsafeAllocator$4.newInstance(UnsafeAllocator.java:108)
    at com.gilecode.yagson.com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$17.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:261)
    ... 42 more

This is the code context that we have in multiple files to parse the json to an object
val cp = gson.fromJson(reader, RequiredClass::class.java)
This line of code for parsing a json to an object was working fine in Java 11, but not in Java 17.
As reflection is revoked from Java 16 and later, is Gson compatible with Java 17. If so, is there any proven workaround for this errors.

This might be a useful resource.

Can you please add the complete exception message and stack trace including all "causes"? That would make it clearer for which class this exception is occurring.

@Marcono1234 added the complete stacktrace.

I would suggest migrating from GSON to a better serialization lib that has actual kotlin support and is not entirely based on reflection.

In general the latest Gson versions support Java 17 and even Java 21. However, Gson uses reflection for classes for which no built-in or custom adapter has been registered. And these JDK versions strongly encapsulate JDK internals (JEP 403). So if you previously (by accident) relied on reflection-based serialization of JDK classes, then you will encounter an InaccessibleObjectException and have to write a custom TypeAdapter for that class, see the Troubleshooting Guide for more information.
A few additional points:

Based on the exception stack traces it looks like you are not actually using the official Gson classes, but instead a repackaged class com.gilecode.yagson.com.google.gson.Gson.
That repackaged class seems to be from an older Gson version; use com.google.gson.Gson instead.
As pointed out in the comments, Gson is mainly designed for Java. It might work for some Kotlin features, but not for all (e.g. nullability is not considered). It might be better to use a JSON library with explicit Kotlin support, for example:

https://github.com/square/moshi
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization




Since we use 'com.gilecode.yagson.com.google.gson.Gson' is it compatible to use add a type adapter for the class or is it perfect to change to 'com.google.Gson'.
We will also consider SerDe for Kotlin modules.

@Praveen, the YaGson Gson code seems to contain some custom changes, but I assume it is mostly compatible with the official Gson, so I would recommend to switch to com.google.gson.Gson (or as mentioned above to a JSON library with explicit Kotlin support).

@Praveen, why did you unselect this as accepted answer again? Do you think some information is incorrect, missing or unclear in this answer?

Using a custom adapter might not be the best solution here, because we have a lot of places where we do serDe and it might become a hassle for us. Any alternatives you have for this with which we can parse without registering custom adapters.

@Praveen, have you tried switching to com.google.gson.Gson (instead of the repackaged YaGson classes) from Gson 2.10.1? Maybe that already solves some of the issues. If you encounter this for common JDK classes (e.g. java.time.*) you could check if there are third-party libraries which provide custom adapters for these classes. But otherwise you probably need custom adapters. If reflective access fails for your own classes, then maybe there is something wrong with the configuration, and it might be worth creating a separate question here (with minimal, reproducible example).
